# Selecting string value to inject based on active controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I am attempting to configure a web service where I have 2 controllers, each referencing a repository which in turn references a database connection context. The connection string used in the context depends on which controller is being used. The controllers only know about their respective repositories, the repositories only know about their database context, context only knows about the connection string.

If there was some way to know which controller was in use in InstancePerApiRequest I could write some logic in the composition root to do it, but that doesn't appear to be possible.

Since the InstancePerApiControllerType only works with supported services, I'm not able to do e.g.

```
container.Register(c => 
  new MyDBContext("my string"))
    .InstancePerApiControllerType(typeof(DocumentController))
    .As<MyBaseDBContext>();
container.Register(c => 
  new MyDBContext("my other string"))
    .InstancePerApiControllerType(typeof(WorkflowController))
    .As<MyBaseDBContext>();
```

This is my setup:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

builder.RegisterHttpRequestMessage(config);
builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

var container = builder.Build();

var configurator = new AutofacConfigurator();
configurator.Configure(builder);

var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;

// controllers
container.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(DocumentController).Assembly);
container.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(WorkflowController).Assembly);

// wire up context string for each controller here
// document
container.Register(c =>
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppSettingsNames.DatabaseConnection];
    var newConnectionContext = new SqlServerConnectionContext(connectionString) { ProductID = productId };
    newConnectionContext.Open();

    return newConnectionContext;
}).InstancePerApiRequest()
.As<ISqlServerConnectionContext>()
.As<IConnectionContext>();

// workflow
container.Register(c =>
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppSettingsNames.WorkflowDatabaseConnection];
    var newConnectionContext = new SqlServerConnectionContext(connectionString) { ProductID = productId };
    newConnectionContext.Open();

    return newConnectionContext;
}).InstancePerApiRequest()
.As<ISqlServerConnectionContext>()
.As<IConnectionContext>();
```

Obviously that code always gives me the second connection string since it just overwrites the first configuration.

I've started looking at lifetime scopes, but haven't been able to figure out how or where to configure them to make things work, if they'll work to solve this problem.

I had previously solved this problem with Ninject using an `IHttpControllerActivator` that took a container in the constructor and then used that to replace the binding of the database context object with one using the correct connection string. The problem with that is the database context was being "magically" set up from the perspective of the composition root. I'm hoping to avoid that with Autofac, but it's looking like I might need to explore a similar solution. <del>At least Autofac would give me the option of having one `IHttpControllerActivator` per controller, making things a little more declarative, rather than having logic in there.</del> Tried that, haven't been able to get it working (yet?).

Is there a better/easier way to do this?

UPDATE:

Maybe these simpler classes might make the structure clearer. In this case I want RepositoryA to get ConnectionA and inject that into Controller A, and RepositoryB gets ConnectionB and is injected into ControllerB:

```
interface IController
{
    string Go();
}

interface IRepository
{
    string Connect();
}

interface IConnection
{
    string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}

class ControllerA : IController
{
    private IRepository _repository;
    public ControllerA(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public string Go()
    {
        return "Controller A" + _repository.Connect();
    }
}

class ControllerB : IController
{
    private IRepository _repository;
    public ControllerB(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public string Go()
    {
        return "Controller B" + _repository.Connect();
    }
}

class RepositoryA : IRepository
{
    private IConnection _connection;
    public RepositoryA(IConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }

    public string Connect()
    {
        return String.Format("Repository A Connected to {0}", _connection.ConnectionString);
    }
}

class RepositoryB : IRepository
{
    private IConnection _connection;
    public RepositoryB(IConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }

    public string Connect()
    {
        return String.Format("Repository B Connected to {0}", _connection.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems a little odd that you don't have multiple reposistory interfaces.  Doesn't each repository have its own methods for doing unique work.  If not, you should be able to use named instances.  I haven't used Ninject, but I'd imagine they support registering and resolving passing a name in addition to the interface type.

Comment: We do, but all of them eventually have a dependency on an IConnectionContext which is the specific database connection. That's the one I'm having trouble resolving because it needs to be set per API request, depending on which controller is active for that request.

Comment: So, 1 Repository class will use a different connection string depending on the calling Controller?

Comment: @Adam47 Exactly. All repositories (eventually) take a dependency of IConnectionContext which is how they know which database to communicate with. IConnectionContext is the object that has a connection string, and that is the object that needs to vary the configuration based on which controller is being used for the current request. Eventually we could end up with objects other than IConnectionContext, but we're always going to need to configure them based on which Web API controller is being used.